# How to install gcc-6 on Debian Jessie next to default gcc? ("standalone installation")

Tags: linux, debian

I'm running Debian Jessie which uses `gcc` v4.9.2. As I'm running into the limitations of the c++14 support in this version I'd like to upgrade it to a newer version.

`gcc-6` is available in the Debian testing repositories, however as it would replace the current `gcc` and associated libraries, I can't install it without upgrading and breaking 100+ packages.

Is it possible to install `gcc-6` and its required libraries next to the current v4.9.2 so I won't break my current Debian installation?

Answer (score -2):

You can make gcc 6 from sources.
Visit https://gcc.gnu.org/ for choose version

Comment: How would you recommend OP goes about building`gcc` 6 from source?